# Copy multiple values from a variable into a new variable in unix

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

We have a variable abc, its is constantly updated with a different value unknown to the user. i need to store all the  value of abc in another variable say bcd. 
lets consider a case we have a variable abc

```
    abc="123" 
    abc="456"
    #value of abc keeps on updating with a value not known to the user
```

now lets consider a variable bcd

```
     bcd="all values of abc:$abc"
```

here i would get only the last value of abc. i would like to have all the updated values in a single variable how can we achieve this in unix

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your use case, but it kind of sounds like you want to keep the previous values around as abc gets updated.  In which case, how about [arrays](http://www.livefirelabs.com/unix_tip_trick_shell_script/nov_2003/11102003.htm)?  The last element would be the most recent value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have all values of $abc concatenated to $bcd just do $bcd=$bcd.$abc

Not sure i you really want to, $abc could get very long if you're not careful.

--update--
In ksh do this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
bcd="all values of abc:"
abc=123
bcd=$bcd" "$abc
echo $bcd
abc=456
bcd=$bcd" "$abc
echo $bcd
```

Running the script:

```
all values of abc: 123
all values of abc: 123 456
```

Comment: i tried does not work, i am writing a ksh script. it keeps only the last value.  for eg abc="123"
abc="456"
bcd=$bcd.$abc
echo $bcd  result is .456

Comment: in your example you have taken a new variable 'b'. what i would be considering is the same variable 'a' being populated with different values and its result stored in variable 'b'

Comment: Thanks Rob the above code works, but we are saving the value in bcd everytime the value of abc changes cant we do something like abc="123" abc="456" cat bcd>>$abc  so that we have all the values of abc in bcd at once

Comment: Sure. How are you going to use the stored values? Could you explain the context of your question?

Comment: I tired to re arrange my code and your code works Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

Each time that variable `abc` changes (or each time you wish to append its value to variable `bcd`), say the following:

```
bcd="$bcd,$abc"
```

Note, it is slightly cumbersome to avoid an extra comma (or other delimiter) at one end or the other of `bcd`.  To avoid that problem, you can set a variable called (eg) `bcdSep` to `""` before the first appending, and to `","` thereafter; and use `bcd="$bcd$bcdSep$abc"`.

Here's an example of use (with `>` indicating prompt):

```
> bcd="The values are "; bcdSep=""
> abc="123"
> bcd=$bcd$bcdSep$abc; bcdSep=","; echo $bcd
The values are 123
> abc=456
> bcd=$bcd$bcdSep$abc; bcdSep=","; echo $bcd
The values are 123,456
> abc=789
> bcd=$bcd$bcdSep$abc; bcdSep=","; echo $bcd
The values are 123,456,789
```

As illustrated above, follow each change of `abc` with the statement `bcd=$bcd$bcdSep$abc` [or with `bcd=$bcd$bcdSep$abc; bcdSep=","` as it's ok to keep setting `bcdSep=","`].

Comment: i tried it. it keeps the last value of abc, it does not keep all the values

Comment: It works ok in bash; I haven't tried with ksh

Comment: i am wiriting a .ksh script

Comment: I tried the one with ur updates in ksh below is my code snippet  abc="123"
abc="456"
bcdsep=","
bcd="$bcd$bcdsep$abc"
echo $bcd   result is ,456

Comment: @Rahulsawant, see added example.  If you want to set several values of abc while doing nothing else in between, use an array and subscript each abc ref

Comment: True the above code works, but cant we do something like this:  abc="123"  abc="456"  cat bcd>>$abc.  cause in the above example we have are saving in bcd evertime the value for abc changes. cant we save all the values in the end ?